# Refresh UI from a method running asyncronously on another project

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I had a winform using a method on another project thought a DLL, test, count and returns 2 values (good files and bad files) and show up on the winforms those 2 results once done.

Ive been asked to improve that winform to show up results in real time, since the work and the test can take up to 30mins, but ive been struggling since i'm beginning in async programmation.

Ive tried to call function with out or ref, without success. As far i tried, i can refresh in real time a local variable, but not one running in the method out of the winform project.

Winform :

```cs
public static int goodfiles { get; set; }
public static int badfiles { get; set; }
Task workControl;
Task refreshControl;

private async void Winform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     myprogressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;                
     workControl = Task.Run(() => WorkMethod());                
     refreshControl = Task.Run(() => RefreshMethod());
                
     await executerControl.ConfigureAwait(true);         
}

private void RefreshMethod()
{
     while (!workControl.IsCompleted)
     {
          label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
          {
               label1.Text = goodfiles.ToString();
               label2.Text = badfiles.ToString();
          }
     }
}

private void WorkMethod()
{
     goodfiles = 0;
     badfiles = 0;
     var Work = new WorkClass();
     Work.ControlFiles(goodfiles, badfiles);
}
```

Class library project

```cs
public class WorkClass
{
     public void ControlFiles(int goodfiles, int badfiles)
     {
          //Do stuff
          var Test = new TestClass();
          Test.TestFiles(goodfiles, badfiles);
     }
}



public class TestClass
{
     public void TestFiles(int goodfiles, int badfiles)
     {
          //Test files
          if(stuff) goodfiles++;
          else badfiles++;
     }
}
```

I know it's maybe far from being the prefect architecture, but I have to deal with it.

Is it technically possible, difficult or just impossible to do? Or am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: Forget about `Invoke`. Use the `Progress<T>` class to post progress information from the background threads to the UI thread.

Comment: You need to use an instance of the WinForm and make sure the WinForm object doesn't close. See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: You may find this interesting: [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

Comment: Ive tried Progress<T> but couldn't manage to make it work tought methods.
Thanks for the docs, i'll peek at them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the same fields from the worker thread and UI thread. The best way is to put them in a shared object. This might be the work-class, but you could also create a separate object that is given as a parameter to the actual work-method. I recommend against using any mutable static fields.

```
public class WorkClass
{
    public volatile int GoodFiles;
    public volatile int BadFiles;
    public void ControlFiles()
    {
        //Test files
        if (stuff) GoodFiles++;
        else BadFiles++;
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
WorkClass myWork;
private async void Winform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     myWork = new WorkClass();         
     workControl = Task.Run(() => myWork.ControlFiles());                    
}
```

To check the progress I would recommend a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=net-5.0). Set it to run however often you want, and update the labels from the `myWork`-object when event handler for the Tick-event. You can await the workControl-task and stop the timer when the task is done.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how coupled or uncoupled you want your code to be.

In most cases, the [Progress class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) is a good choice.

Here's an article from [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) on the subject: [Reporting Progress from Async Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html)